# How do we transfer oracle port 1521 to another machine's port 9800

Tags: oracle, port, firewalld

I want to transfer oracle A port 1521 to B 9800 with firewalld,where I can use B:9800 to visit A's oracle.
I set a new tnsnames.ora which have B:9800

here is the code i test ,but it doesn't work

```sh
firewall-cmd --add-port=9800/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-forward-port=port=1521:proto=tcp:toaddr= B:toport=9800
firewall-cmd --reload
```

I had tried,when i use tnsping to test the new tnsname,I got the “ORA-12569：TNS：包校验和失败”

Answer (score 1):

I have know that.
First,i should input the command on the machine B which i want visit A:1521 via port 9800.
Second,i should modify the /etc/sysctl.conf,and add 'net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1',and then 'sysctl -p' to make it work.